# How to use Ramda pipe?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

### Background

I am trying to compose 2 functions using Ramda, but I am having issue with `pipe`, meaning I don't know how to use it.

### Code

Let's imagine I have a function that returns an array:

```
var createQuery = params => [ getSQLQuery( params ), [ getMarket() ] ];

var getSQLQuery = ( { lang } ) => `My query is ${lang}`;

var getMarket = () => "en_en"
```

So, when calling `createQuery({ lang: "es" })` I would have the following output: `[ "My query is es", ["en_en"] ]`;

Now, let's also assume I am a nasty boy, and I wanna tap this vital information!

```
R.tap(console.log, createQuery({lang: "es"}))
```

A composition ( well, a pipe, to be precise ) would be:

```
R.pipe( 
    createQuery( {lang: "en"} ), 
    R.tap(console.log) 
);
```

Which returns a function.

### Problem

Now let's say I want to execute said function:

```
var comp = params => R.pipe( 
        createQuery( params ), 
        R.tap(console.log) 
    )(params);

comp({lang: "uk"}); //Blows Up!?
```

Why is my function blowing up with `f.apply is not a function` ?? 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you don't have a type checker telling you what's wrong with the intermediate types (of your partially applied functions).

Comment: I am confused. I fail to see how this is an error that could come from type checking.

Comment: ftor, so passive aggressive lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is because you are calling `createQuery(params)` and then trying to treat the result as a function.

You're example function `comp` can be updated like so:

```
const comp = params => R.pipe(createQuery, R.tap(console.log))(params)
```

and `R.pipe` will pass `params` and argument to `createQuery`, the result of which is then given to the result of `R.tap(console.log).

This can be simplified to the following, by removing the immediate application of `params`:

```
const comp = R.pipe(createQuery, R.tap(console.log));
```

Comment: Ok, fair enough. But what if `comp` takes 2 params instead of 1, and `createQuery` only uses the second argument? How would you do it then? Also, upvoted!

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix How do you mean? Like this `const comp = (params1, params2) => R.pipe(createQuery, R.tap(console.log))(params2)` ? An alternative to that would be `const comp = R.flip(R.pipe)(createQuery, R.tap(console.log));` if I am not mistaken.